# Como puedo generar un ticket y varios detalles de tickets en un mismo formulario?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

Estoy teniendo inconvenientes en entender como funcionan las relaciones con tablas intermedias o pivote.

Por un lado tengo mi tabla de `productos` con los siguientes campos:

```php
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('ptype_id');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('brand_id');
    $table->foreign('brand_id')->references('id')->on('brands');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('model_id');
    $table->foreign('model_id')->references('id')->on('models');

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Y tambien tengo mi tabla de `tickets`:

```php
Schema::create('tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('cuenta_id');
    $table->foreign('cuenta_id')->references('id')->on('customers');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('contact_id');
    $table->foreign('contact_id')->references('id')->on('contacts');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('statusTicket_id');
    $table->foreign('statusTicket_id')->references('id')->on('estados_tickets');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('typeTicket_id');
    $table->foreign('typeTicket_id')->references('id')->on('tipo_tickets');
});
```

Y mi tabla intermedia `DetallesTickets`:

```php
Schema::create('detalles_tickets', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->id();

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('ticket_id');
    $table->foreign('ticket_id')->references('id')->on('tickets');

    $table->unsignedBigInteger('product_id');
    $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');

    $table->integer('serial_number');
    $table->integer('quantity');
    $table->text('commentary');
    $table->string('file')->nullable(); //La direccion de la imagen que se sube del remito

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

Ahora yo tengo una vista donde cargo mi producto y hasta ahi todo bien. Pero ahora cree una vista para generar tickets y detalles de tickets pero nose como almacenar registros en ambas bases de datos utilizando un solo formulario.

Debo usar un controlador para `DetalleTickets` y otro controlador para `Tickets`? o como puedo hacer?

Este es mi formulario:

```xml
<div class="card-body">
  <form method="post" action="" id="myForm">
    @csrf
    <h5>Informacion del ticket</h5>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label>Estado ticket</label>
        <select name="" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="">Seleccionar </option>
          <option value="">1.Ingreso</option>
          <option value="">2.Trabajando en Superí</option>
          <option value="">3.Enviado a laboratorio</option>                            
          <option value="">4.Devuelto de laboratorio</option>
          <option value="">5.Presupuesto enviado a cliente</option>
          <option value="">6.Reparado - Pendiente de cobro</option>
          <option value="">7.Listo para entrega a cliente</option>
          <option value="">8.No tiene reparación</option>
          <option value="">9.Cerrado</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="">Tipo de ticket</label>
        <select name="" class="form-control  " required id="">
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
          <option value="">1.Raparación</option>
          <option value="">2.Consulta</option>
          <option value="">3.Pedido Presupuesto</option>     
        </select>                       
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="">Cliente</label>
        <select name="" class="form-control  " required id="">
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        </select>                       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <hr>
    <h5>Producto</h5>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>Numero</label>
        <input type="text" name="ticket_no" id="ticket_no" class="form-control form-control-sm text-white" value=""  readonly style="background:#030335e8">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="brand_id">Marca</label>
        <select name="brand_id" class="form-control select2 " required id="select-brand">
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="ptype_id">Tipo de Producto</label>
        <select name="ptype_id" class="form-control select2" id="select-ptype" required>
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="model_id">Modelo</label>
        <select name="model_id" class="form-control select2" id="select-model" required>
          <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
        </select>
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group col-md-1">
        <label>Numero de serie</label>
        <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-control form-control-sm " value=""   style="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.card-body -->
  <div class="card-body">
    <hr>
    <br/>
    <h5>Laboratorio</h5>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="description">Descripcion de fallas</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descripcion" class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="description">Descripcion de reparacion del laboratorio</label>
        <textarea type="text" name="description" id="description" placeholder="Descripcion" class="form-control form-control-sm"></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="description">Fecha de envío al laboratorio</label>
        <input type="date" name="" id="" placeholder="" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-2">
        <label for="description">Fecha de devolución del laboratorio</label>
        <input type="date" name="" id="" placeholder="" class="form-control form-control-sm">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="coin">Moneda de Costo del laboratorio</label>
        <select name="coin" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="">Moneda </option>
          <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
          <option value="USD">USD-O</option>
          <option value="USDB">USD-B</option>                            
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Costo</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5>Resumen de costos</h5>
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="coin">Moneda de Costo </label>
        <select name="coin" class="form-control" required>
          <option value="">Moneda </option>
          <option value="ARS">ARS</option>
          <option value="USD">USD-O</option>
          <option value="USDB">USD-B</option>                            
          <option value="EUR">EUR</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="change_type">Tipo de cambio</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" name="change_type" id="change_type"  class="form-control" required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Costo de mano de obra</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Costo de mano de obra (ARS)</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Costo de repuestos</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Costo de repuestos (ARS)</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Precio de venta</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Margen Bruto</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        <label for="fob">Margen Bruto (ARS)</label>
        <input type="number"   step="00.01" id="" name="fob" class="form-control"  required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row new_customer" style="display: none;">
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Nombre (Obligatorio)">
         </div>
         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
           <input type="text" name="company" id="company" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Empresa">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="mobile_no" id="mobile_no" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Telefono (Obligatorio)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="mobile_two" id="mobile_two" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Telefono 2">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="mobile_three" id="mobile_three" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Telefono 3">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="E-mail (Obligatorio)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="position" id="position" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Puesto">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="city" id="city" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Ciudad">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="address" id="address" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Direccion">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="postal" id="postal" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Codigo Postal">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="cuit" id="cuit" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Cuit (Obligatorio)">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
            <input type="text" name="website" id="website" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Website">
          </div>
        </div>
```

Y este es mi controlador de ticket:

```php
public function add()
{
    $ticket['tipoTickets'] = TipoTicket::all();        
    $ticket['estadoTickets'] = EstadoTicket::all();
    $ticket['cuentas'] = Customer::all();
    $ticket['contacts'] = Contact::all();
    $ticket['ptypes'] = Ptype::all();
    $ticket['brands'] = Brand::all();
    $ticket['models'] = ModelP::all();
    
    return view('backend.ticket.add-ticket', $ticket);
}

public function store(Request $request)
{
    /*dd($request->all());*/
    $ticket = new Ticket();

    $ticket->ptype_id = $request->$ptype_id;
    $ticket->brand_id = $request->$brand_id;
    $ticket->model_id = $request->$model_id;
    $ticket->serial_number = $request->serial_number;

    $ticket->failure_desc = $request->failure_desc;
    $ticket->repair_desc = $request->repair_desc;
    $ticket->labTerceros = $request->labTerceros;
    $ticket->entryDate = $request->entryDate;
    $ticket->deliverDate = $request->deliverDate;
    $ticket->lab_coin = $request->lab_coin;
    $ticket->lab_cost = $request->lab_cost;

    $ticket->cuenta_id = $request->cuenta_id;
    $ticket->contact_id = $request->contact_id;
    $ticket->statusTicket_id = $request->statusTicket_id;
    $ticket->typeTicket_id = $request->typeTicket_id;
    $ticket->idOwner = Auth::user()->id;
    $ticket->short_description = $request->short_description;
    $ticket->description = $request->description;
    $ticket->save();
    
    Session::flash('success');
    return redirect()->route('tickets.view');
}
```

Es posible que en este mismo controlador cargue tambien registros en la tabla detallesTickets? Como deberia hacer? El hecho de estar intentando hacer esto es para poder hacer que haya muchos productos en un ticket.

Comment: Por supuesto que se puede! Yo que también manejo Laravel, guardo hasta en 3 tablas distintas con un mismo formulario, solo que tengo mi sistema algo diferente al tuyo, yo uso un prototipo de Form Request, y no sabria como explicarte en tu forma de guardar... Se que mi respuesta no ayuda en nada pero al menos te confirmo que si se puede(?) xD

Answer (score 1):

partamos por ver que relaciones hay entre tus tablas.

#### BelongsTo

- La tabla `products` tiene los `brand_id` y `model_id` como llaves foráneas a `brands` y `models` respectivamente. Un *Product* "le pertenece a" un *Brand* y a un *Model*.
- Lo mismo para los campos `cuenta_id`, `contact_id`, `statusTicket_id` y `typeTicket_id` en la tabla `tickets`.
- Lo mismo para los campos `ticket_id`, `product_id` en la tabla `detalles_tickets`.

```php
# Product.php
public function brand()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Brand::class);
}

public function model()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Model::class);
}
```

```php
# Ticket.php
public function cuenta()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Cuenta::class);
}

public function contact()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Contact::class);
}

public function status_ticket()
{
    // Laravel espera que la columna para esta relación sea status_ticket_id. Como no lo es, hay que especificar en el 2° parametro.
    return $this->belongsTo(StatusTicket::class, 'statusTicket_id');
}

public function type_ticket()
{
    // Laravel espera que la columna para esta relación sea type_ticket_id. Como no lo es, hay que especificar en el 2° parametro.
    return $this->belongsTo(TypeTicket::class, 'typeTicket_id');
}
```

```php
# DetalleTicket
public function ticket_id()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Ticket::class);
}

public function product_id()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Product::class);
}
```

#### HasOne/HasMany

Esta relación es la inversa de BelonsTo. Si un `Ticket` está siendo referenciado en otro lado (por ejemplo, en la tabla `detalles_tickets` mediante la columna `ticket_id`, entonces un *ticket* tiene uno (o muchos) *detalles_ticket*.

```php
# Product.php
public function detalles_ticket()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DetalleTicket::class);
}
```

```php
# Ticket.php
public function detalles_ticket()
{
    return $this->hasMany(DetalleTicket::class);
}
```

#### BelongsToMany

Este tipo de relaciones son las relaciones M:N (Un *ticket* puede estar asociado a uno o muchos *productos* y a su vez, un *producto* puede estar asociado a uno o *muchos* tickets mediante una tabla pivote como `detalles_tickets`).

```php
# Product.php
public function tickets()
{
    // Laravel espera que la tabla pivote entre Product y Ticket tenga el nombre product_ticket. Como no es el caso, hay que especificarlo en el segundo parámetro)
    return $this->belongsToMany(Ticket::class, 'detalles_tickets');
}
```

```php
# Ticket.php
public function products()
{
    // Laravel espera que la tabla pivote entre Product y Ticket tenga el nombre product_ticket. Como no es el caso, hay que especificarlo en el segundo parámetro)
    return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'detalles_tickets');
}
```

#### Guardar modelos asociados en el controlador.

Con estas relaciones que se definieron, puedes acceder a ellas para ir guardando los datos.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $ticket = new Ticket;
    ...
    $ticket->save(); // Ahora $ticket debería tener id.

    $detalle_ticket = new DetalleTicket;
    $detalle_ticket->product_id = $request->...;
    $detalle_ticket->serial_number = $request->...;
    $detalle_ticket->quantity = $request->...;
    $detalle_ticket->commentary = $request->...;
    $detalle_ticket->file = $request->...;

    $ticket->detalle_tickets()->save($detalle_ticket);
}
```

Si quisieras crear el ticket, el producto y detalle_ticket al mismo tiempo podría quedarte algo así el método dependiendo de tu formulario.

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $ticket = Ticket::create([/* los datos del ticket */]);
    $product = Product::create([/* los datos del product */]);

    $ticket->products()->attach($product, [/* los datos del detalle_ticket que no son el ticket_id o el product_id */]);
}
```

Para que `create()` funcione bien debes dejar explícito en tus modelos que campos debería manejar.

```php
# Product.php
protected $fillable = ['campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3', ...];
```

```php
# Ticket.php
protected $fillable = ['campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3', ...];
```

Comment: El metodo store que tiene ticket y detalle ticket debe ser en cualquier controlador o en alguno especifico? Yo estoy haciendolo en TicketController donde primero se guardaría el Ticket y despues El detalleTicket, no es asi?

Comment: Puedes hacerlo en cualquier controlador realmente. La cosa es como te ordenas tú. Si quieres hacerlo en ticketcontroller hazlo en ticketcontroller.

Comment: Como puedo hacer para a DetalleTicket pasarle el id del ticket que acabo de guardar? No se si se entiende. Osea en la primera parte del metodo store estoy guardando el ticket. Lo que quiero hacer es que ese id que tiene pasarselo a la segunda parte de mi metodo donde guardo el detalleticket.

Comment: Después de hacer `$ticket->save();`, la id estará disponible en la variable `$ticket`. `$ticket->id`.

Comment: Pero como se lo paso? Porque no sería mediante request. Sería                $detalle_ticket->ticket_id = ticket->id?

Comment: Claro, así mismo. `$detalle_ticket->ticket_id = $ticket->id;`. O bien le dejas al método de relación preocuparse por eso. (`$ticket->detalles_ticket()->create(['campo1' => valor1, 'campo2' => valor2, ...]` Con esta notación no te tienes que preocupar de pasarle el id.)

Comment: Hice la primera opcion y obtengo, creating default object from empty value

Comment: tienes ticket_id entre los campos `$fillable` en tu modelo DetalleTicket?

Comment: Ya lo solucione, cuando cambie algunos campos del controlador me habia quedado el new DetalleTicket(); despues de algunos request y no al principio